# Django.Wsgi.Apache. Error 403 in Apache2

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

There are two website made on Django. Their config files are same (renamed  the names, the paths to the projects). But First is working and Second not working.

There are two website made on Django. Their config files are the same (renamed  the names, the paths to the projects). But First is working and Second not working.

```
firstweb.conf.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/firstweb/firstweb/wsgi.py
    ServerName firstweb.com
    Alias /static /var/www/firstweb/static
    <Directory /var/www/firstweb>
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now from the second site(twoweb) I have got the error 403 (Forbidden).
Access to the projects:

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 andrey andrey 4096 июл 14 14:19 firstweb
drwxrwxrwx 3 andrey andrey 4096 июл 14 14:28 twoweb
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank and sorry for my english.

Comment: Sorry can't help you with the problem but there is also a https://ru.stackoverflow.com . If you have problems explaining yourself maybe they can help you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Deny from all`. That is telling Apache to block your requests. Even though you are specifying order, Apache may be getting confused due to having both that and `Allow from all` in the same context.

Comment: Thank you. I have removed `Deny from all` but it was still not working.  Defined this configuration `Order allow,deny`   `Allow from all`   `Require all granted` and it began to work.

Comment: You can't get rid of the ``Order`` and ``Allow`` directives if on Apache 2.4, use just the ``Require`` directive.